# Running "cordova build android --release" displays unexpected content and no apk

Tags: cordova

Here are the steps I took to compile my html content into a Cordova Android apk:

In Terminal on the Mac, type "cd" then drag the app's file icon into Terminal, click on Terminal to select it, then hit enter to run it.

**Typed in terminal:**

cordova build android --release

**Got result:**

Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=/Users//Library/Android/sdk

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
studio

**Comment:**

That's it. I'm perplexed by this result. It should the steps it is taking and end with the location the apk was created in. A look at the docs showed that I made the command correctly:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html

I have released this multiple times with different updates. I don't understand why it is different this time. There are no error messages.

**Environment:**

iMac, MacOS High Sierra, V10.13.3

cordova -v = 8.0.0

cordova platform ? = android 7.0.0, ios 4.3.1

Edit:
Wow, this is really troublesome. After restarting the computer, I did a new "cordova create" of my project, "add platform android" and 2 plugins and ran "cordova build android --release" again. Same result! When I added --verbose to the command, the only thing that seemed odd was the line "This app does not have additional resource files defined." I don't know what that means; could it be significant?

I opened Android Studio and installed the latest SDK numbers that line up with the numbers in config.xml. Same result.

**Edit:** I went through /platform/android and don't see any /res folder. Half the folders seem to be missing when I compare them to a project created a few months ago. These are probably the "additional resource files" not at hand.

**Edit:** I again did platform rm android, platform add android, cordova build android, and still only a few folders are created under /platforms/android:

/app

/cordova

/CordovaLib

/platform_www

... in addition to: android.json, build.gradle, project.properties, settings.gradle, and wrapper.gradle.

Folders missing, based on earlier project:

/assets

/build

/gradle

/libs

/res

/src

... in addition to: AndroidManifest.xml and gradlew.

**Edit:** I performed a "cordova build android --release" on a cordova project made Sept. 2017 containing all of its /android folders -- and got the same terminal results! **So the error is not app-specific.**

Comment: did you `cordova platform add android` ?

Comment: Yes. I did a rm then an add to make sure. As you can see, "android 7.0.0" is installed.